# How to define foreign keys on mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am working on Mongo DB (4.2) schema validation using $jsonSchema. I want to define foreign key using the $jsonSchema. Is it possible? 
Here is an example of what i want.

Collection Customer -> { customerid, customerName, customerAddress }

Collection Order -> { orderId, customerid, orderdate, orderdetail }

```
    db.createCollection("order", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "orderId", "customerId", "orderdate", "orderdetail" ],
         properties: {
            orderId: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            customerId: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
               **can i define some link here that this customer ID should come from customer collection**
            },
            orderdate: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            orderdetail: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            }
         }
      }
   }
})
```

I want to fulfill following scenarios with $jsonSchema:
1) When i go to insert in orders collection, if the customer in that customer collection does not exist then order insert should fail.
2) If customer gets deleted all orders corresponding to it should also get deleted.

Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: I don't believe you can check referencial integrity with JSON Schema. (Additionally, mongodb isn't really designed to do that anyway. - https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/thinking-documents-part-2)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to specify in `$jsonSchema` that a field must have a value that depends on anything outside of the current document itself.